# Nuxt refresh router view when router :id parameter changes

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

My Nuxt app loads a link and it's child view on the route `http://127.0.0.1/user/:id`. I put the API calls for the user in `mounted` hook of the router view.

If route `id` changes, mounted is not triggered anymore because the child view is already loaded. I ended up with solution - watch the $route.params.id and moved the API call from mounted to this watcher.

```
  watch: {
    $route() {
      this.getRows()
    }
  }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution 1

Force the reload when the `route` changes defining a `:key` for the `<nuxt-child>`, like this:

```
<nuxt-child :key="$route.fullPath"></nuxt-child>
```

---

### Solution 2

Put the API call to load the user in a `watch` to the `id` coming from the URL instead to `mounted`, you can use `immediate: true` to call it in the fist load.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
        user: null
    }
  },
  asyncData({ params }) {
    return {
      id: params.id
    }
  },
  watch: {
    id: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(id) {
        //Call the API to get the user using the id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this works, thanks. The downside is the whole view is refreshed including view transition and everything.

Comment: Yes, you right! I just added another solution to avoid this in the answer.